# Unable to assign values to numpy array in cython

Tags: numpy, initialization, cython, numpy-ndarray

I am fairly new to parallel programming in cython and I was trying to create a 1D array of size 3 from numpy, however I am unable to assign values to this array unless I specify it element by element.

```
    import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as cnp

    cdef int num = 3
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim = 1] Weight = np.ones((num), dtype = "int")
    Weight[2] = 6
    print(Weight)
```

Output -> [1 1 6]

```
    Weight = cnp.ndarray([1,2,3])
```

Output -> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 3)

Comment: The second example should be `np.array(...)` instead of `cnp.ndarray(...)`

Comment: Works, but won't it be like defining a new NumPy array in python with the same array name even though it's already created using cython?

Comment: If you don't want to initialize the array twice then just skip `np.ones((num), dtype = "int")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I suggested changing:

```
Weight = cnp.ndarray([1,2,3])
```

to

```
Weight = np.array([1,2,3])
```

---

Just to clarify my comment a bit more:

The line

```
cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim = 1] Weight = np.ones((num), dtype = "int")
```

is effectively two parts:

1. `cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim = 1] Weight`

   a declaration only. This allocated *no* memory, it merely creates a variable that can be a reference to a numpy array, and which allows quick indexing.
2. `Weight = np.ones((num), dtype = "int")`

   This is a normal *Python* call to `np.ones` which allocates memory for the array. It is largely un-accelerated by Cython. From this point on `Weight` is a reference to that allocated array and can be used to change it. Note that `Weight = ...` in following lines will change what array `Weight` references.

I therefore suggest you skip the `np.ones` step and just do

```
cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim = 1] Weight = np.ones([1,2,3], dtype = "int")
```

Be aware that the only bit of Numpy that using these declarations accelerates is indexing into the array. Almost all other Numpy calls happen through the normal Python mechanism and will require the GIL and will happen at normal Python speed.